# How to select a checkbox from a multiple select box using selenium webdriver in java?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have the below code for the multiple select box in the web page and I need to
    make a selection of any option group for the list using selenium
    webdriver

```
<div class="ms-drop bottom" style="display: block;">
    <div class="ms-search">
        <ul style="max-height: 250px;">
            <li class="group">
                <label class="optgroup" data-group="group_0" style="display: block;">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="selectGroup">AmaWaterways
                </label>
            </li>
            <li class="multiple" style="width: 180px;">
                <label style="display: block;">
                    <input type="checkbox" data-group="group_0" value="AmaSerena" name="selectItem">AmaSerena
                </label>
            </li>
            <li class="multiple" style="width: 180px;">
                <label style="display: block;">
                    <input type="checkbox" data-group="group_0" value="AmaPura" name="selectItem">AmaPura
                </label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can somebody suggest how to select an option group of my choice?

Comment: you want to select only single option at a time

Comment: Try this: 
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='valid element id']//input[text()='AmaWaterways']")).click();

Answer (score 0):

In order to toggle a checkbox, it is as simple as clicking it.

```
String targetOption = "whatever";
By targetOptionLocator = By.cssSelector("input[type=checkbox][value=" + targetOption + "]");
driver.findElement(targetOptionLocator).click();
```

You may also want to check if a checkbox is already checked: [WebElement#isSelected](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#isSelected%28%29).

E.g.:

```
void selectOption(String optionName) {
  By targetOptionLocator = By.cssSelector("input[type=checkbox][value='" +  + optionName + "']");
  WebElement option = driver.findElement(targetOptionLocator);
  if(!option.isSelected())
    option.click();
}
```